# Facebook Oauth Login With Jquery Mobile #_=_

Tags: jquery, facebook, mobile, oauth

When I try to login using Facebook Oauth all goes ok until the part the url redirects with something like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/facebookoauthbackpage.php#_=_
```

I'm using jQuery Mobile on my pages and I think that #*=* is the problem.

The page stays blank and nothing happens. If I remove the "#*=*" all goes alright and the action happens normally.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix that? I've notice that removing the "#*=*" from the Facebook will not be possible anymore, so maybe removing something from the jQuery mobile script may solve that with javascript, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 17):

You could try to forcefully remove the hash at the beginning of your html, something like

```
<script>
if (window.location.hash == "#_=_")
        window.location.hash = "";
</script>
```

Theoretically the routine will be called before $(document).ready :) (never tried it on jquery mobile though)

Comment: Yea, this is basically the solution. Where on earth does the `_=_` come from?

Comment: "This week, we started adding a fragment #_=_ to the redirect_uri when this field is left blank. Please ensure that your app can handle this behavior." --> https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/

Comment: This works great, been searching for a solution to this all day - Caio you should approve the answer unless anyone else has a better idea.

Comment: placing the code before document load, worked for me too. Caio should accept the answer.

Comment: > "This week, we started adding a fragment #_=_ to the redirect_uri when this field is left blank. Please ensure that your app can handle this behavior." - I don't have good words about this! @ErwinMSaputra Thanks, for solutuion.